# mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /web/cgi-bin/php-fcgi

Tags: php, android, mysql, apache

I am getting the following error in php linux based server, hosted in godaddy wordpress theme

**Error Message**
"Service Unavailable
  The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later

Apache server at wwww.checkmoviereview.com Port 80"

The problem is occurring only in certain system, for me its not working and for my friends and godaddy support people its working. There is not much traffic also in my site.

I recently created a php page for an android app, i think that is the culprit for not closing the connection. Can someone help me what I am doing wrong in the code. Once i start using the newly created code it will give 503 error and after some hours it will start working again"

**Code**

```
<?php
mysql_connect(<username & password I am giving here>);
mysql_select_db(<db name i am giving here>);
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once('wp-blog-header.php'); 

$i =0;
$rate_query = null;

$rate_query =  new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'movies', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => 'wtf_rscore','posts_per_page'=>'20' ) );

while ($rate_query->have_posts() ) : $rate_query->the_post();
$rcat=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wtf_category', true);
$rscore=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wtf_rscore', true);
$rdirec=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wtf_dirctr', true);
$rgenre=get_the_term_list( $post->get_the_ID, 'movie-genre', '', ', ', '' );    

if ($rcat == 'Bollywood') 
echo  get_image_url() . ",,," . get_the_title() . ",,," . $rscore . ",,," . get_the_content('Read the rest of this entry &raquo;') . ",,," . $rdirec . ",,,". $rgenre . ",,,"; //I am using this echo result in java program

$i = $i + 1;
endwhile; 

mysql_close();
$rate_query = null;
?>
```

**Error log information from server**

```
[Thu Oct 10 03:58:38 2013] [11814296] [fcgid:warn] [client 106.76.211.138:44799] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /web/cgi-bin/php-fcgi
[Thu Oct 10 03:58:42 2013] [11814296] [fcgid:warn] [client 106.76.211.138:44567] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /web/cgi-bin/php-fcgi
[Thu Oct 10 03:58:46 2013] [11814296] [fcgid:warn] [client 106.76.211.138:2152] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /web/cgi-bin/php-fcgi
[Thu Oct 10 03:58:50 2013] [11814296] [fcgid:warn] [client 106.76.211.138:37856] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /web/cgi-bin/php-fcgi
[Thu Oct 10 03:58:54 2013] [11814296] [fcgid:warn] [client 106.76.211.138:24984] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /web/cgi-bin/php-fcgi
[Thu Oct 10 03:58:58 2013] [11814296] [fcgid:warn] [client 106.76.211.138:54537] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /web/cgi-bin/php-fcgi
[Thu Oct 10 03:59:03 2013] [11814296] [fcgid:warn] [client 106.76.211.138:32542] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /web/cgi-bin/php-fcgi
[Thu Oct 10 03:59:09 2013] [11814296] [fcgid:warn] [client 106.76.211.138:26424] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /web/cgi-bin/php-fcgi
[Thu Oct 10 03:59:21 2013] [11814296] [fcgid:warn] [client 106.76.211.138:37370] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /web/cgi-bin/php-fcgi
[Thu Oct 10 03:59:57 2013] [11814296] [fcgid:warn] [client 106.76.211.138:21834] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /web/cgi-bin/php-fcgi
[Thu Oct 10 04:02:57 2013] [11814296] [fcgid:warn] [client 106.76.211.138:40323] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /web/cgi-bin/php-fcgi
[Thu Oct 10 04:03:01 2013] [11814296] [fcgid:warn] [client 106.76.211.138:26866] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /web/cgi-bin/php-fcgi
```

Comment: do you have a apache or lighttpd server?

Answer (score 1):

I am facing same issue and found more godaddy customers are facing the same.
http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/fcgid-internal-error/

Looks like godaddy had some change triggered this erros, spoke to support but solution is to use dedicated or virtual hosting plan.